# SSE works locally, but not when deployed to Vercel

Tags: javascript, express, stream, vercel, server-sent-events

I have a proxy server which makes a request to OpenAI which returns a Readable Stream object. The proxy server takes this readable stream object and pipes the events back to the client.

My code works as intended when deployed locally, but once deployed to Vercel it does not.

When deployed locally:

- The SSE connection is established
- The data is received in many small chunks
- The 'Transfer-Encoding' header is present with a value of 'chunked'

When deployed on Vercel:

- The SSE connection is not established, instead it is treated like a regular REST API call.
- The data is received in one big chunk
- The 'Transfer-Encoding' header is NOT present, instead there is a 'Content-Length' header which is unexpected.

```
app.post('/completions', (req, res) => {
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream');
    res.setHeader('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked');
    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
    res.setHeader('X-Accel-Buffering', 'no');
    res.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');

    const headers = {
        'Authorization': `Bearer MY_AUTH_TOKEN`
    };
    const body = {
        'messages': []
    };

    axios
    .post(
        'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions',
        body,
        {
            headers: headers,
            responseType: 'stream'
        }
    )
    .then((open_ai_response) => {
        open_ai_response.data.pipe(res);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        res.status(500).send(err);
    })
});
```

Comment: You tagged the question with Streaming SIMD Extensions (SSE). Are you sure that's correct? Please read the tags before you use them. The SSE tag contains: _"(For Server-Sent Events use [server-sent-events] tag instead)"_

Comment: @jabaa SSE as in Server-Sent Events (SSE)

Comment: @jabaa: this mis-tagging is common, you have more than 2k rep so just edit it when you see it.  Only worth commenting (or writing something in the edit message) when someone tags both [sse] and [server-sent-events], to remind them to look at the mouseovers when it looks like there might be 2 tags for the same thing.  It would be nice if people checked the tags they're using in all cases (especially short abbreviations like [sse]), but that's a lost cause.

Comment: @PeterCordes I think my comment is helpful because many people don't even know that tags have descriptions. Of course, I can fix the tags myself in the future, but I would also add a comment.

Comment: @PatTrudel The SSE tag stands for Streaming SIMD Extensions. If you mean Server-Sent Events, you need a different tag: `server-sent-events`. Peter Cordes fixed it for you. You should read the description in the future.

Comment: Got it, wasn’t aware, will make sure to check that out next time, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**: *You need to use the Edge runtime*

It looks like you might be using a [Next.js custom server](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/custom-server). According to that link (after the first paragraph):

> Note: A custom server cannot be deployed on Vercel.

This is due to the limitations of Vercel (and serverless platforms in general), specifically the [serverless function execution timeout](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/limits/overview#serverless-function-execution-timeout). Prior to the introduction of Vercel's Edge Runtime, it was not possible to stream data to the client. Fortunately, the Edge Runtime *does* support Server-Sent Events, and the [documentation for streaming events](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/functions/edge-functions/streaming) even points to an example using the GPT3 API.

You might also read the page about [Next.js Runtimes](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/edge-and-nodejs-runtimes).

> "Both runtimes can also support streaming **depending on your deployment infrastructure**."

On Vercel, the Node runtime is always deployed as serverless, thus not compatible with Server-Sent Events.

Finally, [this discussion](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/48427) might have useful information (although the method used here is for hosting providers supporting server*ful* Node runtimes.